# After deploying Magento 2, I am getting a persmissions error for static/pub

Tags: magento-2.1

I am in developer mode, and have ran php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy to deploy a custom CSS file. I am now getting this error when loading my website:

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): The path "_requirejs/frontend/AZ/az/en_US/requirejs-config.js:///home/xxx/public_html/xxx/pub/static/home/xxx/public_html/xx/pub/static/" is not writable

I have changed the permissions of pub and static to 777.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in developer mode, the pub/ folder will automatically regenerate itself when you visit the frontend. Separate deployment is only necessary in production mode.

You can try clearing the pub folder with:
`rm -rf pub/static/*` and then visit the frontend.

Also, you may have an error somewhere in your code, because the path in your error message looks wrong:

`"_requirejs/frontend/AZ/az/en_US/requirejs-config.js:///home/xxx/public_html/xxx/pub/static/home/xxx/public_html/xx/pub/static/`

Comment: Hey that actually did work, and cleared that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please, not that 777 permission is a security issue if used on Production server. Magento Community recommends to set 777 permissions only when installing new modules and then reset permissions back to safe values.

**Permissions to install modules and update Magento software:**

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

**After install, must secure directories by resetting recommended directory 
permissions:**

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 400 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 500 {} \; 
find var/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \; 
find media/ -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find var/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; 
find media/ -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
```